# Add Extension after variable

Tags: javascript, customization, attr, file-extension

I have some javascript that I am using for some audio on my website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var a = audiojs.createAll({
            trackEnded: function() {
                var next = $("ul li.cow").next();
                if (!next.length) next = $("ul li").first();
                next.addClass("cow").siblings().removeClass("cow");
                audio.load($("a", next).attr("duck"));
                audio.play();
            }
        });
        var audio = a[0];
        first = $("ul a").attr("duck");
        $("ul li").first().addClass("cow");
        audio.load(first);
        $("ul li").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).addClass("cow").siblings().removeClass("cow");
            audio.load($('a', this).attr('duck'));
            audio.play();
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I'd like to do is add ".mp3" after the attribute "duck"...how do I do that? *Attribute "duck" appears three times and I would like to add the extension ".mp3" after all three :)

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're asking about simple string addition? Then just add

```
+ ".mp3"
```

after each attr('duck')

Comment: Worked like a charm, although I could have sworn I tried that!! lol

Answer (score 2):

To change their attributes:

```
$("ul a").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("duck", $(this).attr("duck") + ".mp3");
});
```

To change the string only:

```
first = $("ul a").attr("duck") + ".mp3";
```

Comment: I tried to change all the elements using the script you provided, but for some reason I couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: Except the foreach function you wrote above, that's what I couldn't get to work :)